# Floating Multiple Elements Right Correctly Within Menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this has been asked before but I'm having trouble getting it to work in my case. I'm trying to display a menu bar with a search option and inline text to its left.  When I float both right, either way, I can't get the desired order.  Here's the jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z8f890Ln/

I tried to fix it by using containing divs and using this code:
HTML

```
    <div class="right">
    <span class="navbar-text">
         Navbar text with an inline element
     </span>
    <div class="right-right">
    <form>
         <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
         <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 button-arrow" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.right{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
.right .right-right{
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Im am not exactly sure what you want ?

Comment: are you trying to make it responsive or fixed width. if you are trying for responsive you need to write much more CSS and test properly for all resolution. if it fixed design make sure all element has enough width to fit next to each other.

Comment: Responsive.  Trying to have the correct order of floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the extra CSS classes. Just use the `navbar-form navbar-right`...

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          Navbar text
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

http://www.bootply.com/pqNzsnRKJ7#

Comment: Thank you!  Just got it working, but my solution was really convoluted compared to this solution.

Comment: Who else loves Bootstrap!